# QueryBuilder with One To Many relationship and several conditions using Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship, query-builder

I will try to explain my issue as well as I can. I have a Message related to another Entity called Reply (one message can have zero or n replies) and I want to take into account the following cases:

1. If UserA have one message created to UserB (UserA is the creator)
   but the UserB didn't replied the message I don't want get message

---

2. Same as above but the UserB replied to the message. I want get the
   message with its replies if replies exists

---

3. If the UserB sent a message to UserA, I want to get the message with
   its replies if replies exists

My Message Entity (I will just put the OneToMany relantionship):

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
* @ORM\Table(name="messages")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MessageRepository")
*/
class Message {

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ReplyMessage", mappedBy="message")
*/
private $replies;

/**
 * Add replies
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ReplyMessage $replies
 * @return Message
 */
public function addReply(\AppBundle\Entity\ReplyMessage $replies)
{
    $this->replies[] = $replies;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove replies
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ReplyMessage $replies
 */
public function removeReply(\AppBundle\Entity\ReplyMessage $replies)
{
    $this->replies->removeElement($replies);
}

/**
 * Get replies
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getReplies()
{
    return $this->replies;
}
```

And the code that I am using to achieve my objective is the following:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('message')
    ->where('message.creator = :username or message.receiver = :username')
    ->leftJoin('message.replies', 'replies')
    ->andWhere('replies.user = :username')
    ->setParameter('username', $username)
    ->getQuery();

$sent = $query->getResult();

return $sent;
```

I am not an expert building queries with Doctrine and I don't know how can control all my cases right now, if someone could help I'd be very grateful

Comment: Shouldn't `getReplies()` already have every Reply, because it's a relation? Also maybe self-referencing relations can help you become way more dynamic too. In the doctrine page they used `User` as an example. Sometimes you want to have "friends" which are also just "User" objects. So you can use the User Object as self-reference. A reply is a Message too, so I am sure you can self-reference it too and with the power of symfony, you should get the data very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the beauty of QueryBuilders. You can create statements like this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('message')
    ->where('message.creator = :username or message.receiver = :username')
    ->leftJoin('message.replies', 'replies')
    ->andWhere('replies.user = :username')
    ->setParameter('username', $username);

if (some_condition) {
    $query->andWhere('some_property');
}

if (some_other_condition) {
    $query->andWhere('some_property');
}

return $query->getQuery()->getResults();
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `->getResult();` in you `AppBundle\Repository\MessageRepository` repository, becose sometimes you need use him meny times, and for example: `BreadcrumbsBundle` need query (not result, еhis is affected by performance)